# Raspberry Pi 4 drops hdmi connection for a second at boot tv reconnects, drops signal again after playing any type of video

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, pi-4, troubleshooting

I've been having a terrible experience with my raspberry pi 4 4G, with regards to a strange problem that's occurring. I am currently running NOOBS with raspbian/libreelec, and everytime after entering the desktop (Raspbian) the TV reconnects for a second or two...

Same thing happens when playing a video of any kind (in both systems Rasp & Libre), and i literally am racking my brain on how to fix this issue.

The Pi is not powering down or rebooting at all, and as long as i DO NOT launch a video either in VLC, Chrome in Raspbian or video in Libreelec no reconnecting will happen.

I have tried every single configuration i could find on the web, by tinkering with various hdmi settings in the config files of both systems, but alas nothing seems to work.

I've swapped HDMI cables, checked my SD card, reinstalled everything, checked the PSU,(<--The Original Rasp one) nothing seems to be working. Everything is properly cooled and nothing is overheating, almost no peripherals are inserted except for a bluetooth dongle (onboard bluetooth sucks)<==also troubleshooted this by removing the dongle btw...

Now here's the weirdest part of all... I think it might be some kind of audio over HDMI handshake issue, because when i plug the HDMI cable into the HDMI 1 connection (The one that does not support audio at the moment) the reconnecting does NOT happen.

What am i supposed to do now? I am kind of at a loss at the moment...

Can anyone help me out?

***UPDATE I MIGHT HAVE FOUND THE ROOT OF THE PROBLEM SEE POST BELOW!!!***

Comment: Have you updated your Raspbian recently? There's been a load of changes to Raspbian since the RPi4B was introduced in June.

Comment: It does sound like a power supply issues. Do you have another one you could try?? When you say original raspberry pi supply. Do you mean for the original pi or just that it's the genuine power supply. The new pi4 model requires more power than the older models so if it is the PS for an older model it may not be supplying enough power.

Comment: Hi guys first of all thanks for helping me out.

Everything is up to date system wise.

Sadly I don't have another power supply lying around, it's the original power supply for the pi 4. The Pi is not shutting down/rebooting, but the hdmi connection is dropping for a second or two, specifically after playing video and right after it boots to the desktop in Raspbian.

Can't imagine it being a psu issue.

Comment: Here's the img of my power supply: Raspberry pi psu. https://imgur.com/gallery/6RL7kQJ

Comment: I have been able to pinpoint the issue! Pulseaudio disturbs the connection between my tv and the Raspberry pi, when i disable Pulse and play the media everything works! No blanking/reconnecting etc... I actually removed and reinstalled Pulse to test this out, and now i am at a loss because what the hell is going on?

But without Pulse there is of course no sound output.

What can i do to resolve this strange issue? Is there any kind of setting or  tweaking i can do to get pulse to play nice with my TV? 

Help suggestions are more than welcome!

Comment: I foolishly thought it was Pulseaudio... It's definitely an issue with my television, don't understand what's going on exactly but it's definitely weird as heck. Here's a video example of what's going on with the TV: https://imgur.com/gallery/n2bRnWE